# How does a Safenet eToken Pass(hardware token) generates OTP and based on which algorithm? How does authentication takes place against it?

Tags: authentication, one-time-password

I use hard token to login to a VPN but I don't get the concept behind it.The password is combination of a self generated PIN + OTP generated on eToekn Pass. How do authentication takes place at back end and what is criterion for OTP expiration?

Comment: @iserni Sorry for adding comment here as I was not able to comment to your answer..so does that mean that each hard token has its own IV and the server knows that IV? What if a user notes down a OTP(on pressing the button on eToken) and uses that OTP to login at some later point of time (considering the case that he did not press the button again making the noted down OTP to be valid) ? Will it be authenticated since timestamp at later point of time would be different?

Answer (score 4):

Supposing the counterpart knows your PIN, *and* the initialization vector for your eToken, then all that it's needed is that the eToken has a **clock**.

Using some amplification scheme, possibly involving the IV again, the timestamp (usually with one minute resolution) is converted into a large enough buffer to undergo encryption inside the eToken. From that, a token is extracted and shown on the display.

When you send your username, PIN and eToken data, the server simply runs the same calculation using the IV it has in its database, and verifies that all the data match (optionally, the token values for one minute before and one minute after the present time may be tested, in order to correct small clock drifts).

```
--> username, PIN   -->      "user suraj has IV 12345 and it's now
                              june 10, 2016, at 17:12. Encrypting
                              this date with 12345 yields a number
                              whose last six digits are 488690."
--> token 488690    -->      "YES! You are logged in."
```

Using standard six-digit eTokens, and without access to the IV that was burned into the eToken memory, there is one chance in a million that an attacker is able to generate a valid token, even if he did have your account login and PIN.

(Usually, also, these systems will lock after three or five attempts to enter an incorrect token).

Comment: The wiki is a good reference https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm

Answer (score 1):

The eToken Pass has two modes to operate.
Eventbased and Timebased. The basic for these are [RFC4226](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226) and [RFC6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238). **BUT** Safenet changed the event based tokens this way, that they do not use SHA1 anymore but SHA256, which is - strictly speaking - not HOTP compliant.

The event based OTP values does not expire. You can press the button now and use the OTP value tomorrow.

The time based OTP value is only valid within a time window, which is defined by the authentication backend.

The "IV" mentioned by @Iserni is a 20 byte (SHA1) or 32 byte (SHA256) symmetric key, which is unique to the token.

```
OTP = truncate(HMAC-SHA1(Key + Counter))
```

The counter is either the event counter (key presses) or the unixtime/30.

The server component knows the last counter and calculates an OTP value and compares the OTP value the user provided with the OTP value the server calculated. More in the RFCs.